# laptop's power state on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

How can I find out the power state(whether it's plugged to a power source, or not) of a laptop running on Ubuntu? I need to use that info. to trigger a python script, so I want to know if there is a way to do this using Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu [has support](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dapper/acpi-support) for the [acpi](http://www.lesswatts.org/projects/acpi/) protocol. By using the `-b` flag, you can get battery info.  One way you may want to use this is:

```
import os
os.system("acpi -b > batteryinfo.txt")
#code to parse batteryinfo.txt
```

Having to parse the batteryinfo.txt file may be a bit of a pain.  In addition you will have to set up permissions because normally `acpi` is only run as root.

Comment: got this: sh: acpi: not found

Comment: Did you try it as root, sudo acpi ?

Comment: I was under the impression that it would be installed by default, but in anycase, you can get it from the ubuntu package repo.  Use 'sudo apt-get install acpi-support`.  See the first link my post for more info

Comment: yes, it works after installing acpi; but sudo acpi gives `Battery 0: Full, 100%`, so there's no info whether laptop is plugged to AC power and the python script you gave just prints 0

Comment: Right, the python result will always be 0 because python is returning the result code of the execution.  The only time it won't be 0 is if the executed command to `os.system` fails and returns -1.  That is why you have to pipe the result to the textfile, and then open and parse the textfile.
Try running without the `-b` flag, I do believe acpi will indicate whether or not you are plugged in, but I am not on a linux box at the moment.  Check out `man acpi` for more info.

Answer (score 2):

On a sufficiently modern Ubuntu you might want to use [DBus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus) (via [its Python binding](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html)) to [query the DeviceKit daemon](http://hal.freedesktop.org/docs/DeviceKit-power/Power.html).

*Update*: actually, on modern Ubuntu installations DeviceKit-power is replace by [UPower](http://upower.freedesktop.org/) (but that's got its own, very similar [DBus interface](http://upower.freedesktop.org/docs/ref-dbus.html)).